# How to load an .rssdk file as input to the realsense sdk

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, realsense

I want to load a saved .rssdk file as input to my realsense application. I saw the below code from examples.

```
pxcCHAR fileName[1024] = { 0 };
PXCSenseManager *psm = PXCSenseManager::CreateInstance();
PXCCaptureManager* captureManager = psm->QueryCaptureManager();
captureManager->SetFileName(fileName, false);
psm->QueryCaptureManager()->SetRealtime(false);
```

But my problem is how to give my file name (suppose "out.rssdk") to this pxcCHAR fileName??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pxcCHAR` is just a wchar:

```
typedef wchar_t pxcCHAR;
```

so you can just use a wchar literal:

```
pxcCHAR fileName[1024] = L"out.rssdk";
```

and other wchar stuff like `std::wstring`.